# Including Jquery Library from a external scource

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I am trying to include the following jquery library:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

When I run the bellow code alert is not displayed:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left:0px; width:20px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <form id="payment_form" action="https://arembepe.net/Tester3.php" method="POST">
        Número do cartão: <input type="text" id="card_number"/>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
alert(123);
</script>
```

However when I run the same code without the reference to the jquery library the alert is displayed:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left:0px; width:20px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <form id="payment_form" action="https://arembepe.net/Tester3.php" method="POST">
        Número do cartão: <input type="text" id="card_number"/>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js"></script><script>
alert(123);
</script>
```

After reading comments I change the code to:

```
    <div style="float: left; margin-left:0px; width:20px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <form id="payment_form" action="https://arembepe.net/Tester3.php" method="POST">
            Número do cartão: <input type="text" id="card_number"/>
            <br/>        
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
                alert($("#card_holder_name").val());
    </script>
```

With this new code I manage to make alert(123) display. But When I try to use a alert($("#card_holder_name").val()); I get "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" I can't use any jquery function.

Comment: When you include a `src` attribute value, the body of the `<script>` is ignored. Use two `<script>` tags - one for jquery, and one for your local script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left:0px; width:20px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <form id="payment_form" action="https://arembepe.net/Tester3.php" method="POST">
        Número do cartão: <input type="text" id="card_number"/>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
alert(123);
</script>
```

**Edit**: This works without error :

```
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        alert(123);
    </script>
    <body>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left:0px; width:20px; padding-top: 10px;">
            <form action="https://arembepe.net/Tester3.php" id="payment_form" method="POST">
                Número do cartão:
                <input id="card_number" type="text"/>
                <br/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. But by doing this I get the following  message: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when I try to use a Jquery Selector.

Comment: I added correction in my post, and it seems to work as intended

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
<script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    alert(123);
  </script>
```

you forgot the ending and starting script  tags. Correct it to:

```
<script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   alert(123);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a script source that tag will only run the script at that source, so you simply need to add a third script tag.  Your code:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left:0px; width:20px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <form id="payment_form" action="https://arembepe.net/Tester3.php" method="POST">
        Número do cartão: <input type="text" id="card_number"/>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
alert(123);
</script>
```

should become this instead:

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left:0px; width:20px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <form id="payment_form" action="https://arembepe.net/Tester3.php" method="POST">
        Número do cartão: <input type="text" id="card_number"/>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://assets.pagar.me/js/pagarme.min.js"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
alert(123);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `<script src="url"></script>`

The `src` attribute is optional. If it is present, then its value is a `url` which identifies a `.js` file.

The content between the `<script src="url">` and the `</script>` should be blank.
If it contain somethings.it is ignored

If the `src` attribute is not present, then the content text between the `<script>` and the `</script>` is compiled and executed.